# Extract function calls from the right hand side of a formula

Tags: r

Several functions in R treat certain functions of variables on the right hand side of a formula specially. For example `s` in `mgcv` or `strata` in `survival`. In my case, I want particular functions of variables to be taken out of the model matrix and treated specially. I can't see how to do this other than using `grep` on the column names (see below) - which also doesn't work if `f(.)` has not been used in the formula. Does anyone have a more elegant solution? I have looked in `survival` and `mgcv` but I find the code very hard to follow and is overkill for my needs. Thanks.

```
f <- function(x) {
    # do stuff  
    return(x)
}

data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), 
        x1 = rnorm(10), 
        x2 = rnorm(10), 
        s = rnorm(10))

formula <- y ~ x1 + x2 + f(s)

mf <- model.frame(formula, data)
x <- model.matrix(formula, mf)

desired_x <- x[ , -grep("f\\(", colnames(x))]
desired_f <- x[ , grep("f\\(", colnames(x))]
```

output:

```
> head(desired_x)
  (Intercept)          x1         x2
1           1  0.29864902  0.1474018
2           1 -0.03192798 -0.4424467
3           1 -0.83716557  1.0268295
4           1 -0.74094149  1.1094299
5           1  1.38706580 -0.2339486
6           1 -0.52925896  1.2866540

> desired_f
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 0.46751965  0.65939178 -1.35835634 -0.05322648 -0.09286254  1.05423067 
          7           8           9          10 
-1.71971996  0.71743985 -0.65993305 -0.79821349
```

Comment: That nearly works, the problem is the hard coded `3` which wouldn't work if the user entered a formula of say `y ~ x1 + f(s)`, or `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3`

Comment: Unfortunately the problem with this approach is if a user entered `y ~ funny_var + f(x)` then it would pick up `funny_var` by mistake. There must be a more elegant solution but I have not manged to figure it out yet!